# Placing string beside a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a very long String of multiple choice questions like this:

```
8. OVERT    (R.R.B. 1996)
(a) Deep    (b) Shallow
(c) Secret  (d) Unwritten
9. ACCORD   (Railways, 1991)
(a) Solution    (b) Act
(c) Dissent     (d) Concord
```

I want to place this options [(a)(b)(c)(d)] beside the question with a tab like this :

```
8. OVERT    (R.R.B. 1996)   (a) Deep    (b) Shallow (c) Secret  (d) Unwritten
9. ACCORD   (Railways, 1991)    (a) Solution    (b) Act (c) Dissent     (d) Concord
```

I've used `"\b"` before the `(a)` like this:

```
newString = QuestionString.replace("(a)", "\b(a)")
```

But this only removes some spaces before the `(a)`.But I want to remove the line break before it.Can someone suggest me how can I get rid of it using python ?

Comment: Can't you just replace the line break with a space or something like that? `string.replace('\n', ' ' )`

Comment: No,I can't.But why are you asking this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
string = """8. OVERT    (R.R.B. 1996)
(a) Deep    (b) Shallow
(c) Secret  (d) Unwritten
9. ACCORD   (Railways, 1991)
(a) Solution    (b) Act
(c) Dissent     (d) Concord"""
string = string.replace("\n(a)", "\t(a)")
string = string.replace("\n(c)", "\t(c)")

print(string)
>>> 8. OVERT    (R.R.B. 1996)       (a) Deep    (b) Shallow (c) Secret  (d) Unwritten
9. ACCORD   (Railways, 1991)    (a) Solution    (b) Act (c) Dissent     (d) Concord
`` `
```

Comment: and kudos for not succumbing to regexitis.  this is clearer and certainly much faster than the regex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You may try doing a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```regex
\r?\n(?!\d+\.)
```

This will target all CR?LF which are *not* followed by a digit-dot line which starts the next section.  Make the replacement empty string, to remove such matching CR?LF.

```py
inp = """8. OVERT    (R.R.B. 1996)
(a) Deep    (b) Shallow
(c) Secret  (d) Unwritten
9. ACCORD   (Railways, 1991)
(a) Solution    (b) Act
(c) Dissent     (d) Concord"""
output = re.sub(r'\r?\n(?!\d+\.)', '', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
8. OVERT    (R.R.B. 1996)(a) Deep    (b) Shallow(c) Secret  (d) Unwritten
9. ACCORD   (Railways, 1991)(a) Solution    (b) Act(c) Dissent     (d) Concord
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
\n(\([a-z]\).+)
```

And replace this with

```
\1\t
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/prZTdn/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Se below, it is also OS indepenndent, notice the os.linesep

```
import os
longStr = """8. OVERT    (R.R.B. 1996)
(a) Deep    (b) Shallow
(c) Secret  (d) Unwritten
9. ACCORD   (Railways, 1991)
(a) Solution    (b) Act
(c) Dissent     (d) Concord"""

print(longStr)
longStr = longStr.replace(os.linesep +"(", " (")
print("")
print(longStr)
```